# State restoration and preservation , encoding UILabel

Tags: ios, decode, encode, state-restoration, uikit-state-preservation

```
-(void)encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
NSLog(@"Start encode");
for (int index = 1; index <= [self.view.subviews count]-1; index++) {
    NSString *encodeKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dnumber",index];
    UILabel *label =  self.view.subviews[index];
    [coder encodeObject:label forKey:encodeKey];
    NSLog(@"%@",label);
}

[coder encodeInteger:[self.view.subviews count] forKey:@"count"];

 [super encodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];
NSLog(@"End encode");
}

-(void)decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{

NSUInteger number = [coder decodeIntegerForKey:@"count"];
NSLog(@"Start decode");
for (int index = 1; index <= number-1; index++) {
     NSString *encodeKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dnumber",index];
    UILabel *label = [coder decodeObjectForKey:encodeKey];
    NSLog(@"%@",label);
    [self.view addSubview:label];
}
NSLog(@"End decode");
[super decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:coder];


}
```

The code above is used to encode all the UILabel that I added as subview onto the screen through a for loop. However when decoding the only thing i get is (null) from the console.
Please help.

Comment: you can not encode a ui element, what you can do here is get the text(string) from label & encode them. in the same way decode the text and assign them to your label. you viewcontroller will take care of UI element.

Comment: because i do a for loop to put each of the 20 label at a random position and i wanna make sure they're at the random position after i restart the app. Only the label contains the frame that holds the coordinate of its random position. How do you suggest to solve this then?

Comment: it that case you should create a model object that will hold the frame, text & tag of a label at encoding & while decode assign these frame & text to on tag basis.